# Python: Apply function to every entry in numpy 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to apply a (more complex?) function on my 3d numpy array with the shape x,y,z = (4,4,3). 
Let's assume I have the following array:

```
array = np.arange(48)
array = array.reshape([4,4,3])
```

Now I would like to call the following function on each point of the array:

**p(x,y,z) = a(z) + b(z)*ps(x,y)**

Let's assume a and b are the following 1d arrays, respectively ps a 2d array.

```
a = np.random.randint(1,10, size=3)
b = np.random.randint(1,10, size=3)
ps = np.arrange(16)
ps = ps.reshape([4,4])
```

My intuitive approach was to loop over my array and call the function on each point. It works, but of course it's way too slow:

```
def calcP(a,b,ps,x,y,z):
    p = a[z]+b[z]*ps[x,y]
    return p

def stupidLoop(array, a, b, ps, x, y, z):
    dummy = array
    for z in range (0, 3):
        for x in range (0, 4):
            for y in range (0, 4):
                dummy[x,y,z]=calcP(a,b,ps,x,y,z)
    return dummy

updatedArray=stupidLoop(array,a, b, ps, x, y, z)
```

Is there a faster way? I know it works with vectorized functions, but I cannot figure it out with mine.

I didn't actually try it with these numbers. It's just to exemplify my problem. It comes from the Meteorology world and is a little more complex.

Comment: Do you mean `ps = ps.reshape([4,4])`? There is some error with the ndarrays you've shared

Comment: IIRC you can use the map function to iterate through np.arrays as well so 'map(f, array)' might just do the trick?

Comment: I think you want `dummy = a[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + b[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * ps` (according to the snippet, because in the formula you wrote first the indices are in different order, so it would be `a + b * p[:, :, np.newaxis]`).

Comment: @jdehesa and @yatu thanks for pointing out the mistakes. 
The new variable (in my case `updatedArray` should have the exact same dimensions as my old variable `array`.
And why should I add more dimensions to a, b and ps with `np.newaxis`?

Comment: @meissner_, The `map` function will only iterate over the **outer** dimension of a numpy array. It does not understand the inner dimensions.

Comment: @fountainhead: orly? that seems strange but good to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using `numpy.fromfunction()`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,10, size=3)
b = np.random.randint(1,10, size=3)
ps = np.arange(16)
ps = ps.reshape([4,4])

def calcP(x,y,z,a=a,b=b,ps=ps):
    p = a[z]+b[z]*ps[x,y] + 0.0
    return p

array = np.arange(48)
array = array.reshape([4,4,3])

updatedArray = np.fromfunction(calcP, (4,4,3), a=a,b=b,ps=ps, dtype=int)
print (updatedArray)
```

Notice that I've modified your function `calcP` slightly, to take kwargs. Also, I've added `0.0`, to ensure that the output array will be of `float`s and not `int`s.

Also, notice that the second argument to `fromfunction()` merely specifies the shape of the grid, over which the function `calcP()` is to be invoked.

**Output (will vary each time due to randint):**

```
[[[  8.   5.   3.]
  [  9.   6.  12.]
  [ 10.   7.  21.]
  [ 11.   8.  30.]]

 [[ 12.   9.  39.]
  [ 13.  10.  48.]
  [ 14.  11.  57.]
  [ 15.  12.  66.]]

 [[ 16.  13.  75.]
  [ 17.  14.  84.]
  [ 18.  15.  93.]
  [ 19.  16. 102.]]

 [[ 20.  17. 111.]
  [ 21.  18. 120.]
  [ 22.  19. 129.]
  [ 23.  20. 138.]]]
```

Comment: This is getting so close! Thanks already. 
But I made some minor mistakes in the dimensions. 
Let's say the shape should be (3,4,4). So, 3 layers with each 4*4. 
But when I try to change it to `array.reshape([3,4,4])` and also `updatedArray = np.fromfunction(calcP, (3,4,4), a=a,b=b,ps=ps, dtype=int)`
I get an **IndexError**: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

Comment: Okay I think I got it. I needed to adapt my function as well:
`def calcP(z,x,y,a=a,b=b,ps=ps):
    p = a[z]+b[z]*ps[x,y]
    return p`

Comment: @Sev: You're welcome. If this was helpful, pls upvote the answer (click on the grey up arrow icon). Also pls click on the tick mark icon to "Accept" the answer so others will know this has been answered..

Comment: Note that this solution will be slower than the broadcasting, and by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @NilsWerner:How so? And what exactly is being broadcasted in that solution?

Comment: @NilsWerner: Maybe I haven't understood what you mean by "the broadcasting". As far as I can see, there is broadcasting involved in this solution also, and the function `calcP()` gets called exactly once, and its arguments consist of the  **matrices** `x`, `y`, and `z` (and **not scalars**), and each of those matrices is in the final broadcasted shape, which is also the shape of `the return value of the function. Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: Look at @JanZhen's solution, it uses broadcasting

Comment: @NilsWerner  That solution isn't clear to me, as it just posts one line without its context, or where that line should go. And even if I understand that solution, it still doesn't explain how my solution is slower by an order of magnitude. I was hoping to get that from you.

Comment: That one line solution *just works*, just run it! And use `%timeit` to compare their runtimes

Comment: @NilsWerner  Asking me to timeit is different from explaining how you reached that conclusion.

Comment: Because `fromfunction` will have to leverage fancy indexing, which broadcasting doesn't have to do.

Comment: Thanks. OP mentioned clearly that there could be a more complex function to be used in the place of `calcP()`. Therefore the solution provided shouldn't be too tangled up with the dummy function given. I don't think the broadcasting solution, as currently posted, fits the bill. I don't think it's even a valid answer to the posted question. (Sure, given a new function, you can post a new broadcasting solution.) In the `fromfunction()`  based soln, even if the return value expression changes, the solution will still work, as long as the operations and operators involved can work element-wise.

Comment: As for performance, it's important to understand that broadcasting *does not necessarily involve making copies*. The internal iterators "are adjusted so that each iterator thinks it is iterating over an array with the broadcast size. This is done by adjusting the iterators number of dimensions, and the shape in each dimension". This essentially means that a broadcasting-based solution is internally doing fancy indexing of its own, and has **no performance benefit** over the fancy indexing-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorize the loop, and use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a.reshape([1,1,-1]) + b.reshape([1,1,-1]) * ps.reshape([4,4,1])
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks @NilsWerner for offering a more common way in comment:

```
a + b * ps[:, :, None]
```

Comment: A more common way is to write `a + b * ps[:, :, None]`

Comment: Thanks @NilsWerner . It's better, and I will edit my answer.